# RxJS observe an object

Tags: rxjs

I am new to RxJS so I apologize for the newbie question.

I have a local javascript object defined as:

```js
model.user = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}
```

I am binding each property to an input control where the user can change the values.  I would like to be able to observe this object and capture the event when the value of any of the properties change.

Is this achievable with RxJS?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/ofobjectchanges.md

Comment: Thank you @OlesSavluk.  Do you know if this works for nested properties?

Comment: Not sure, under the hood it uses `Object.observe`. Also keep in mind that it is not supported in most browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @OlesSavluk.  You were right, this does not work on all platforms.  Object.observe() is not available anymore.  The search continues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an object, you can store your entire state as Observable.

Here is the example code (something similar to what people do in redux):

```js
var fnameInput = document.getElementById('fname');
var lnameInput = document.getElementById('lname');
var jsonPre = document.getElementById('json');

var onFirstName$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(fnameInput, 'input');
var onLastName$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(lnameInput, 'input');

var initialState = {
  firstName: '', 
  lastName: '',
};

var state$ = Rx.Observable
  .merge(
    onFirstName$
      .map(e => 
        state => Object.assign(
          state, 
          { firstName: e.target.value }
        )
      ),
    onLastName$
      .map(e => 
        state => Object.assign(
          state, 
          { lastName: e.target.value }
        )
      )
  )
  .scan(
    (state, makeNew) => makeNew(state), 
    initialState
  )
  .startWith(initialState);

state$
  .subscribe(state => {
    jsonPre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(state, null, 2);
  });
```

```html
<input id="fname" type="text">
<input id="lname" type="text">
<pre id="json"></pre>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got one question, where do you get the variable "state" from? The one that you update with Object.assign() in both Observables

Comment: @Borjante it is handled by a `scan` method, starting from `initialValue` and then the next state is created by applying `makeNew` function to the old state.
see - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md