# Correctly Mutating BehaviorSubject Object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

This is a part of my Angular Service:

```js
private user = new User();
private user$ = new BehaviorSubject < User > (this.user);

public getUser(): Observable < User > {
  return this.user$.asObservable().share();
}

public setUser(user: User) {
  this.user$.next(user);
}
```

What's the proper way to change only one field/property of `user` and reemitting the whole object again?

Comment: Have you already tried to make a provider an interface? Try this and you'll see.

Comment: Singleton? Do you mean you want to mutate and re-emit the mutated user every time? And no, it makes no difference whether it's an interface or a class.

Comment: @dbandstra, yes, that's precisely what I mean!

Comment: Hard for me to answer what the proper way is because I'm allergic to mutation, especially with observables like this! Anyway, what are you changing? You could have e.g. a method in the service called `setUsername`, which just mutates `this.user` then re-emits. Remove the `setUser` method and add a private method called `reemitUser` or something that just pushes `this.user`.

Comment: Well, I also do not want to mutate really, this is why I was expecting a suggestion of what you would do instead :) For instance, would you use Object.Assign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model your state as `scan` of events. Each event will generate new state from previous (without mutation).

Take a look at this example - [RxJS observe an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268671/rxjs-observe-an-object/41270535#41270535)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, but if I have a `user` with 15 fields, that becomes a bit lengthy!

Comment: You are not required to create a separate subject for each field. You can create only one Subject for all of them by parametrizing field (pass it as the parameter) or you can create separate Subjects for each event. Just do whatever better for your case